# WinError 5 Access is denied need help saving a matplotlib animation

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, pycharm

I would like to make a manelbrot set zoom animation using matplotlib. I am on Windows 10 and I am using Python 3.7 with PyCharm. The code that produces the animation works really well but I can't manage to save the actual animation on my computer as it always returns [WinError 5] Access is denied. I have tried running PyCharm as an administrator but it didn't work. Here is what the code looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation


plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop'

"""the code that produces the animation"""

mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
animation.save('mymovie.mp4', writer=mywriter)
```

Is there any way to get past this error?

Comment: you did not set `animation.ffmpeg_path` to your `ffmpeg.exe` full path

Comment: @LiorCohen I am sorry but I am new to this. Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: your path looks incorrect. It should be the full path of your ffmpeg.exe.